# How can i store number of wins/lose of currentuser for my hangman game

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering is there any way i can store and retrieve  number of wins and loses till the browser is closed for hangman game in javascript.

Comment: normally store them within a variable but with out some code example to show not sure how its structured?  SomethinG like var wins=0; then in a function say funCtion AddWin(){wins++;} etc (this will be lost on browser refresh / close)

Comment: Until the browser is closed or until the page is closed ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways. Since I don't know any of your implementation I'd probably create objects for the players and store the name and score together. Something like

```
var player1 = {name: John,
              score: 0};
```

then you can update the score by

```
player1.score = 100;
```

edit: If you need the wins and losses seperate you can of course handle them seperatly:

```
var player1 = {name: John,
              wins: 0,
              losses: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prototype:

```
function PlayerDetails(n,s,r){

  this.name = n;
  this.score = s;
  this.rank = r;


}

PlayerDetails.prototype.trackScore = function(){
//your code here
}
```